# How to use argsparse so the script options with the same affect will appear in the same 'help' line

Tags: python

I'm using `argsparse` to parse the options passed to my python scripts.

I want to enable passing '-a', and to allow passing '-b' with the same affect.

No problem, I'll call `parser.add_argument()` twice, with the same description:

```
parser.add_argument('-a', help='do something')
parser.add_argument('-b', help='do something')
```

But now when displaying the script help, I will see both, as such:

```
-a          do something  
-b          do something
```

This is ugly.

I would prefer to have **{-a, -b}** or **{-a|b)**.

I could not find in argsparse documentation any way around this (admittedly, not critical) issue.

Comment: You can send both to the same call of [add_argument](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.add_argument)

Comment: Before diving into option parsers pls make sure you have at least *seen* this: http://docopt.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to pass both arguments to the same `add_argument` call:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-a', '-b',  help='do something')

parser.parse_args(['--help'])
```

output

```
usage: test.py [-h] [-a A]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
  -a A, -b A  do something
```

Comment: That did it. How simple. Thanks.

Comment: wait a sec...  
Now accessing 'args.b' yield a run timer error!

Comment: Yes, you can only access 'args.a' even if you call '-b' option:
`python test.py -b 'my_argument'`
arguments dict will contain : `{'a': 'my_argument'}`

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.